# 'SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression

Tags: matplotlib, plot, python-3.7

I want to plot this numerical solution

```
import math as ma
import numpy as np  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

m=np.array([0, 1, 2, 3])    
x=np.linspace(0,1,1000)
plt.figure()
for i in range (4):
        plt.plot(x, ma.tan(ma.pi*5*x-m[i]*ma.pi/2)=- (0.954)**2*ma.sqrt(0.3**2/x**2-1))
plt.show()
```

but get the following error:

> SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression

Comment: The error is due to the expression/assignment using `=`. Could you clarify whether you wish to plot the function (i.e. `ma.tan(ma.pi*5*x-m[i]*ma.pi/2)- (0.954)**2*ma.sqrt(0.3**2/x**2-1)` against `x` or simply show where the `tan` and `sqrt` expressions are equal (`A==B`) at points along `x`?

Comment: I see your point! I want to plot the left and right hand side, so I can see two graphs and look at their intersection. I tried rewriting the code, but the plot is nowhere near how I would expect it to be, besides, rhs and lhs is the exact same curve...


`
x=np.linspace(0.01,0.3,1000)
rhs=lhs=np.zeros(1000)

for i in range (1000):
    rhs[i]=ma.tan(ma.pi*5*x[i]-2*ma.pi/2)
    lhs[i]=-(0.954)**2*ma.sqrt(0.3**2/x[i]**2-1)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x,rhs,label='rhs')
plt.plot(x,lhs,label='lhs')
plt.legend()
plt.show()`

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe you want:

```
for i in range (4):
    plt.plot(x, np.tan(np.pi*5*x - m[i]*np.pi/2))
    plt.plot(x, -0.954**2*np.sqrt(0.3**2/x**2-1))
```

Unsolicited advice:

- I recommend sticking to NumPy when using arrays; you don't need `math` as well.
- Iterate directly over `m`, rather than indexing into it. In other words, do `for mi in m:` then use `mi` instead of `m[i]`.

Comment: Yes! You got it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user12212883 Don't forget to upvote &/or accept if it helped you!